# error LNK1104 - cannot open *.obj

Tags: visual-studio-2012, linker, linker-errors, ar.drone

I'm trying to build the Parrot ARDrone SDK v1.8 in Visual Studio 2012 Express on Windows 8. I've managed to get all the errors fixed up to this set:

```
1 warning C4201: nonstandard extension used : nameless struct/union
2 warning C4389: '==' : signed/unsigned mismatch
3 warning C4100: 'cfg' : unreferenced formal parameter
4 warning C4100: 'cfg' : unreferenced formal parameter
5 warning C4100: 'cfg' : unreferenced formal parameter
6 warning LNK4006: _gettimeofday already defined in video_stage_recorder.obj; second definition ignored
7 warning LNK4006: _gettimeofday already defined in video_stage_recorder.obj; second definition ignored
8 error LNK1004: cannot open file 'C:\Users\Daniel\ArDrone\ARDrone-1.8\ARDroneLib.obj'
```

I can't seem to find any answers to this error anywhere. Would any of the warnings be a cause for the 1104 linker error? Is there any way I can get more information from VS about what the cause could be?

Any help/suggestions are welcome and appreciated.

Dan

Comment: Have you checked if ARDroneLib.obj is existing in that path?

Comment: It doesn't exist, no. But isn't the .obj only created once the project successfully compiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, it was a PEBKAC issue...

Goofed-up the include references.